# How to create and apply a prefix to a NestJS module and its child modules?

Tags: javascript, typescript, routes, nestjs, nest

I'm working on a NestJS application and I'm trying to set up a prefix for a specific module and have it apply to both the parent module and its child modules. I've defined a module structure like this:

```
/src/api/
  ├── api.module.ts
  └── auth/
       ├── auth.module.ts
       └── controller/
            └── auth.controller.ts
```

In my app.module.ts, I have defined a prefix for the ApiModule like this:

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ApiModule } from "./api/api.module";
import { RouterModule } from "@nestjs/core";

@Module({
    imports: [
        ApiModule,
        RouterModule.register([
            {
                path: "api",
                module: ApiModule,
            },
        ]),
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In my api.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthModule } from "./auth/auth.module";

@Module({
    imports: [AuthModule],
})
export class ApiModule {}
```

However, it seems that the prefix is only applied to controllers in the ApiModule, and controllers in the AuthModule are not affected. How can I set up a prefix that applies to both the ApiModule and its child modules, including AuthModule?

Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you have

```
RouterModule.register([
    {
        path: "api",
        module: ApiModule,
    },
]),
```

The prefix `api` shall be applied to only controllers registered within `ApiModule`, meaning:

```
@Module({
    controllers: [], // within this array
})
export class ApiModule {}
```

---

If your intention is to apply a [global prefix](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/global-prefix) `api` to all your controllers (in every modules), you can instead do this in your `main.ts`:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
```

---

If you need to apply a prefix to only controllers within certain modules, you can instead do:

```
RouterModule.register([
    {
        path: "api",
        module: ApiModule,
    },
    {
        path: "api",
        module: AuthModule,
    },
]),
```